# Liferay web content display different data per user

Tags: web, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, web-content

I am new in liferay. 
Using Liferay 6.2. I have made a custom page template (`D_template`) and all users with user group D takes page template `D_template` by default. 
In this page template I have added `Web Content Display` portlet with `custom structure` and `custom template`.

My problem is when a user add data in this web content portlet then all other users see same data in theirs pages.

I need to change this and every user see theirs data.

How can do that? Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try playing around with page scope for this portlet's configuration?

Comment: Yes but nothing. I try with scope D_template but nothing, with page name .. noting and with global where the data of the conent is same for all users

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure what kind of data you are talking about - whether a static or dynamic data for different users. If its static, you could pretty much write a javascript code in your template to show different content for groups. If its dynamic data retrieval from different data source, I believe you might want to consider writing a portlet for it.